# Changing the caller number in an incoming call in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, ivr

I am using asterisk.I have DID in which 4 numbers are mapped(stored in my database) so when user calls to that DID number  the call is forwarded to the any one number mapped on that did.
My problem is that when user calls  to DID the one of the four executive receive calls from the DID number not with user number .This is my part of dialplan code the call is routed from another context(not given below) to the direct context

```
[direct]
exten => start,1,noop(######START######)
same => n,mysql(Query resultid ${connid} SELECT number from database);;;DDDDDD
same => n,MYSQL(Fetch fetchid ${resultid} number )
same => n,mysql(clear ${resultid})
same => n,set(__NUMBER=${number})
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${NUMBER},20,mM(ANSWEREDED))


[macro-ANSWEREDED]
exten => s,1,noop(CALL_ANSWERED)
exten => s,n,Mixmonitor(/recordings/record.wav)
```

**How can i change the number that flashes on executive number(number mapped on DID) to the caller number?**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Every asterisk book have example. Doing asterisk coding without reading book - not so nice idea

2) callerid can be set like this

```
same => n,set(__NUMBER=${number})
same => n,set(CALLERID(num)=123445678)
same => n,dial(DAHDI/g0/0${NUMBER},20,mM(ANSWEREDED))
```

3) If you use pstn dahdi connection(FXO card), that will not work. If you use digital connection, it can work if provider support that.

4) Use of app_mysql is depricated. Use func_odbc or realtime.

5) Use of mixmonitor inside on-call macro is extremly bad practice. Use mixmonitor with 'b' option before call out.

Comment: thanks arheops, i am using `pstn dahdi connection`,i have tried the above code but it dint work as you said(it will not work for pstn dahdi connection) but i have tried it in outgoing call using call file and it worked there